# Divergência mensagem de aviso de pergunta protegidas

Tags: debate

Quando o usuário está logado a mensagem é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que entendi uma pergunta protegida serve para evitar respostas com agradecimentos e de baixa qualidade, e também para perguntas que tem uma complexidade um pouco maior logo exige mais atenção e não respostas genéricas, mas a mensagem que é exibida para os usuários que não estão no site passa a impressão que as respostas para perguntas protegidas são de baixa qualidade, o oposto da mensagem de um usuário logado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Qual a definição de uma pergunta protegida?

Comment: Relacionada: [Proteger perguntas, quem, quando e porquê?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2430/proteger-perguntas-quem-quando-e-porqu%c3%aa)

Comment: Eu escrevi no final a pergunta por causa da diferença do enunciado. No primeiro diz uma coisa e na outra mensagem diz outra.

Comment: Eu reparei Laerte, mas fica ai essa como relacionada.

Comment: Eu não tenho pontos de reputação pra proteger perguntas, portanto não sei como funciona, mas vou supor que a mensagem escolhida seja semelhante a situação de fechar, uma pergunta foi protegida por motivo e a outra por outro motivo. Ou seja é mais de uma definição, podem ser situações diferentes.